# How to stop “GET” from being logged

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Whenever something is loaded using `href` or `src`, a `GET` is logged in my debug console. **How can I stop this from being logged.**

This happens every time a page is loaded. Using Node.js, Express, and Pug.

In the head

```
link(rel='stylesheet'ref='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3...')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
link(rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/magnific-popup.css')
script(type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.min.js')
script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstr...')
script(src="/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js")
script(src="/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js")
script(src='/js/jssor.slider.mini.js')
script(src='/js/socket.io.js')
```

Debug Console

```
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 8.784 ms - 8668
GET /stylesheets/magnific-popup.css 304 4.629 ms - -
GET /js/jssor.slider.mini.js 304 4.195 ms - -
GET /js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js 304 6.541 ms - -
GET /js/jquery.magnific-popup.js 404 7.940 ms - 40
GET /js/jquery.min.js 304 12.245 ms - -
GET /js/socket.io.js 304 0.623 ms - -
```

Emile Bergeron
It happened during development and now on a live server. Doesn't matter what browser I use.

```
Server Code: 
#!/usr/bin/env node 
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('PhotosAndVideos-master:server');
var http = require('http');
var path = require("path");
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
console.log("listening on port:" + port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

Comment: Could you please show us the express code and the command you use to start the server?

Comment: Please, edit your question to add relevant information in it.

Comment: That's clearly not all of your code since you don't define `onListening` and `onError` in the pasted code.  Whatever is in your app.js file is probably what's doing it, because the default behavior of express will not log anything.

Comment: @Paul You fixed my Problem... Thanks app.use(logger('dev')); in app.js was causing this log. Thanks Again Pat

Answer (score -2, accepted):

can you make sure your debug console is not disabling your browser cache?

[image]

Comment: He didn't ask how to stop the requests from being made, he only ask for them to not be logged in the express debug output.

Comment: Yes - however that depends on which Debug Console he uses. In Firebug debug console you can filter network log by file type. So the view of the log can be cleaned up of these calls. However as long as it is not cached, there would be a GET call.

Comment: It happened during developement and now on a live server. Doesn't matter what rowser I use.Server Code: #!/usr/bin/env node var app = require('../app'); var debug = require('debug')('PhotosAndVideos-master:server'); var http = require('http'); var path = require("path"); var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000'); app.set('port', port); console.log("listening on port:" + port); var server = http.createServer(app); server.listen(port); server.on('error', onError); server.on('listening', onListening);

Comment: That's not remotely true.  He's talking about server-side logging; the browser can't control that regardless of cache status, if the request is made.

Comment: @Paul You fixed my Problem... Thanks app.use(logger('dev')); in app.js was causing this log. Thanks Again Pat

Comment: @Paul, I commented out this line and no more GETs being logged in my Debug Console. I'm hoping you get the credit for the Accepted Answer. Thanks again. Pat

Comment: @P.Nuzum I don't care much if I get the credit or not, but as it stands you Accepted the answer that talks about your browser cache.  You'd be better off answering your own question with the information you gleaned from these comments, and accepting that.